# Extract only folder name right before filename from full path

Tags: r, regex, directory, extract, filenames

I have the following path

```
filePath <- "/data/folder1/subfolder1/foo.dat"
```

I'd like to get `subfolder1` which is where `foo.dat` locates. I saw solutions in other languages but haven't found one in R. What is the simplest way to do it? Thank you!

What I tried

```
> basename(filePath)
[1] "foo.dat"

> dirname(filePath)
[1] "/data/folder1/subfolder1"
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This may solve:

```
filePath <- "/data/folder1/subfolder1/foo.dat"

basename(dirname(filePath))
```

http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=IPftVEDk&version=1

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the prettiest answer, but it will work for you:

```
unlist(strsplit(filePath, '/'))[length(unlist(strsplit(filePath, '/')))-1]
```