# How to replace the title of columns in a merged document with the file directory using R?

Tags: r, merge, directory, rename

I have performed an experiment under different conditions. Each of those condition has its own Folder. In each of those folders, there is a subfolder for each replicate that containts a text file called DistList.txt. This then looks like this, where the folders "C1.1", "C1.2" and so on contain the mentioned .txt files:

[image]

I have now managed to combine all those single DistList.txt files using the following script:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/Experiment/.")

fileList <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "DistList.txt", full.names = TRUE)

listData <- lapply(fileList, read.table)

names(listData) <- gsub("DistList.txt","",basename(fileList))

library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

bind_rows(listData, .id = "FileName") %>%
  group_by(FileName) %>%
  mutate(rowNum = row_number()) %>%
  dcast(rowNum~FileName, value.var = "V1") %>%
 select(-rowNum) %>%
  write.csv(file="Result.csv")
```

This then yields a .csv file that has just numbers a titles (marked in red), which are not that useful for me, as shown in this picture:

[image]

I would rather like to have the directory of the "DistList.txt" files or even better only the name of the folder they are in as a title. I thought that I could do that using the function `list.dirs()` and `colnames`, but I somehow didn't manage to get it to work.

I would be very grateful, if someone could help me with this issue!

Comment: I think this line `gsub("DistList.txt","",basename(fileList))`, should be `gsub("DistList.txt","",fileList)`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! This has worked perfectly fine! If you could add this as an answer, I will directly choose it as the best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line

```
names(listData) <- gsub("DistList.txt", "", basename(fileList))
```

should be:

```
names(listData) <- gsub("DistList.txt", "", fileList)
```

Because by using `basename` we are removing all the folders, leaving us with filename `"DistList.txt"`, and that filename gets replaced by empty string `""` using *gsub*.

We might actually want below instead, [extract the last directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47189479/680068), which should give in your case something like `c("C1.1", "C1.2", ...)`:

```
names(listData) <- basename(dirname(fileList))
```